# pagination error--> undefined index

Tags: php, mysql

This isnt duplicate entry. I have read previous post with same content but i couldnt find the solution. Thats why i have decided to post this.

EDIT 02

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

    <?php



 if (isset($_POST['lab_id']) && is_numeric($_POST['lab_id'])) 
   {         
     $lab_id = $_POST['lab_id']; 
   } 
else if (isset($_GET['lab_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['lab_id'])) 
   {         
     $lab_id = $_GET['lab_id']; 
   } 


//$targetpage = "view_all_chemicallab.php";     
    $limit      = 2; 

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM chemical 
JOIN lab_inventory_chemical ON chemical.chemical_code = lab_inventory_chemical.chemical_code 
WHERE lab_inventory_chemical.lab_id= '$lab_id' ";         // this is line 71 
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query)); 
    $total_pages = $total_pages['num']; 

    $stages = 3; 
    $page =isset($_GET['name'])?mysql_escape_string($_GET['page']): ''; 
    if($page){ 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; 
    }else{ 
        $start = 0;     
        }     

    // Get page data 
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM chemical 
JOIN lab_inventory_chemical ON chemical.chemical_code = lab_inventory_chemical.chemical_code 
WHERE lab_inventory_chemical.lab_id='$lab_id' LIMIT $start, $limit";   //this is line 86 
    $result = mysql_query($query1); 

    // Initial page num setup 
    if ($page == 0){$page = 1;} 
    $prev = $page - 1;     
    $next = $page + 1;                             
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);         
    $LastPagem1 = $lastpage - 1;                     


    $paginate = ''; 
    if($lastpage > 1) 
    {     


   //  $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>

        $paginate .= "<div class='paginate'>"; 
        // Previous 
        if ($page > 1){ 
            $paginate.= "<a href='view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=$lab_id&page=$prev'>previous</a>"; 
        }else{ 
            $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>previous</span>";    } 



        // Pages     
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($stages * 2))    // Not enough pages to breaking it up 
        {     
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++) 
            { 
                if ($counter == $page){ 

                    $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>"; 
                }else{ 
                $paginate.= "<a href='view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=1&page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}
                 //   $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                     
            } 
        } 
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($stages * 2))    // Enough pages to hide a few? 
        { 
            // Beginning only hide later pages 
            if($page < 1 + ($stages * 2))         
            { 
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($stages * 2); $counter++) 
                { 
                    if ($counter == $page){ 
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>"; 
                    }else{ 
                        //$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";
                        $paginate.= "<a href='view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=$lab_id&page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                     
                } 
                $paginate.= "..."; 
                $paginate.= "<a href='view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=$lab_id&page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>"; 
                $paginate.= "<a href='view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=$lab_id&page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";         
            } 
            // Middle hide some front and some back 
            elseif($lastpage - ($stages * 2) > $page && $page > ($stages * 2)) 
            { 
                $paginate.= "<a href='view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=$lab_id&page=1'>1</a>"; 
                $paginate.= "<a href='view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=$lab_id&page=2'>2</a>"; 
                $paginate.= "..."; 
                for ($counter = $page - $stages; $counter <= $page + $stages; $counter++) 
                { 
                    if ($counter == $page){ 
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>"; 
                    }else{ 
                        $paginate.= "<a href='view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=$lab_id&page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                     
                } 
                $paginate.= "..."; 
                $paginate.= "<a href='view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=$lab_id&page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>"; 
                $paginate.= "<a href='view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=$lab_id&page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";         
            } 
            // End only hide early pages 
            else 
            { 
                $paginate.= "<a href='view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=$lab_id&page=1'>1</a>"; 
                $paginate.= "<a href='view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=$lab_id&page=2'>2</a>"; 
                $paginate.= "..."; 
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($stages * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++) 
                { 
                    if ($counter == $page){ 
                        $paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>"; 
                    }else{ 
                        $paginate.= "<a href='view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=$lab_id&page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                     
                } 
            } 
        } 

                // Next 
        if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
            $paginate.= "<a href='view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=$lab_id&page=$next'>next</a>"; 
        }else{ 
            $paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>next</span>"; 
            } 


    $paginate.= "</div>"; 

} 


// get results from database 
     //   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members") 
       //         or die(mysql_error());   

        // display data in table 
        echo "<div>"; 
        echo "<table id='table1'>"; 
        echo "<tr> <th>Chemical Name</th> <th>Chemical Code</th> <th>Type</th> <th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th><th>Stock</th>  </tr>"; 

        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
        { 

                // echo out the contents of each row into a table 
                echo "<tr>"; 
                echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>'; 
                echo '<td>' . $row['chemical_code'] . '</td>'; 
                echo '<td>' . $row['type'] . '</td>'; 
                echo '<td><a href="editchemical.php?chemical_code=' . $row['chemical_code'] . '">Edit</a></td>'; 
                echo "<td><a href=\"delete_chemical.php?chemical_code=" . $row['chemical_code'] ."\" * onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>"; 
                echo '<td><a href="stock_chemical.php?chemical_code=' . $row['chemical_code'] . '">Stock</a></td>'; 
                echo "</tr>"; 


        } 
       echo "</table>"; 
       echo $paginate; 
       echo "</div>"; 


    ?>
```

I am having problem with pagination in php. I have already spent 3 days on this but i couldn't find the error. So finally decided to ask help from you guys.This pagination script simple queries like Select * from employee. But it gives errors when i use join in mysql query(no errors in 1st page. but when i click paginated pages there is no results and error are there).
---errors---
1.Notice: Undefined variable: lab_id in F:\xampplite\htdocs\chem\view_all_chemicallab.php on line 71
2.Notice: Undefined variable: lab_id in F:\xampplite\htdocs\chem\view_all_chemicallab.php on line 86

(error lines are shown in the above code by using commenting option)

please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your script define $lab_id = null; Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `$lab_id` variable is being sent via a `POST` from a form. In your pagination links, you aren't referring to it again. So when you click the link, the server no longer knows what the query is. You need to pass it back to the page again like your other variables (`$targetPage` and `$counter`) so that your query will still be able to be written - that or keep in it a session, or a cookie or something else.

Also, your code is prone to injection attacks. You really should change your code to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). The old `mysql_query` type commands shouldn't be used.

Edit: Try this at the header:

```
if (isset($_POST['lab_id']) && is_numeric($_POST['lab_id'])) 
{         
    $lab_id = $_POST['lab_id']; 
}
else
{
    if(!isset($_GET['lab_id']))
    {
        $lab_id="";
        // this means that the query will fail and you need to
        // make sure that your script never gets to here
    }
    else
    {
        // Do any other checking/verification here
        $lab_id=$_GET['lab_id'];
    }
}
```

This will ensure that lab_id is always set (though it will potentially still be empty, see the code above). But then in your `$targetpage` variable, have something like this:

```
$targetpage = "view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=".$lab_id;
```

Edit 2:
You will have to modify some of your links in the code so that the href tags aren't made to contain two ? in them such as `$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>` as there will already be a ? in the variable `$targetpage`.

Edit 3:
Your code at the moment is:

`$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>"`

The problem is that `$targetpage` already is defined above as:

`$targetpage = "view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=".$lab_id;`

which means when you combine the two you will end up with:

`$paginate.= "<a href='view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=1?page=$counter'>$counter</a>"
// I used lab_id as 1 fot this example`

which is an invalid link. The way to pass more than one parameter is to join them with `&` symbols. This will work for paginate however:

`$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage&page=$counter'>$counter</a>"`

This will result in the link being:

`<a href='view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id=1&page=$counter'>$counter</a>`

which is the correct way to form it.

Comment: $targetpage = "view_all_chemicallab.php?lab_id={$_REQUEST['lab_id']}"; i have done this butsame results.

Comment: In edit 2, a href link cannot: `href="somepage.php?link=1?page=2"`. I mean that you will have to have a look at your code to correct it so that it shows the above link like `href="somepage.php?link=1&page=2"`. You cannot use ? twice in a link, further parameters are joined by using an `&` symbol.

Comment: sorry there was my error in previous comment. This is the correct one. I have tried edit 1--> I got the correct number of paginated pages but when i click on them nothing happens no results obtained only the table headers displayed and specially there are no errors<br/> I didnt get waht u have said in EDIT 02. I am not native English

Comment: I understood what u have said. But i cant figure it out how to correct this bug. Idont know where to put & mark. can u please help me with this by taking $paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a> this as an example.

Comment: i have done as u said but when i click on page numbers nothing happens :( (links are not working). I have edited my 1st post and post what changes that i have made.

Comment: Can you show me an example of the output from the code so I can see how your links are turning out please?